# How to center input in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

My goal is to vertically center the input in the picture. How can I do that?

```css
.headmenu {
  background-color: rgb(47, 47, 47);
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
}

.headmenu-right {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.headmenu-right>input {
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="headmenu">
  <div class="headmenu-right">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You probably want the "can I use flexbox" solution from here: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: This is a handy tool to use http://howtocenterincss.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use flexbox here:

```css
.headmenu {
    background-color: rgb(47, 47, 47);
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;
}

.headmenu-right {
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.headmenu-right>input {
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="headmenu">
    <div class="headmenu-right">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.headmenu {
    background-color: rgb(47, 47, 47);
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:end;
    align-items:center;
}

.headmenu-right {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.headmenu-right>input {
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="headmenu">
    <div class="headmenu-right">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```